# Gallery has too much padding in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, image-gallery

My Flickr gallery looks good in all browsers except IE 7. What else do I need to put in my CSS code for it to not look so lopsided in IE 7. I added the `display: block` but it didn't do anything.

```
a img {
    display: block;
    *display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    padding: 3px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border: 1px solid green; 
    margin-right: 15px; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
```

Right now it looks like this.

[image: Screenshot of Flickr page with too much padding]

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the CSS? Should I be adding in something for IE so it can read it properly?

[This is my site](http://fhlsociety.ca)

Comment: This is why you should use a reset CSS (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). It removes cross-browser inconsistencies in default styles.

Comment: I am creating a child theme of twentyten and it already has the eric meyer CSS reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched even more and found an IE bug arcticle and you have to make sure the line-height in the parent element is set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like the ie step down bug.

Have you tried adding just `display: inline`?

Comment: Have you tried taking all of the margin and padding off to see if they at least line up correctly then?

Comment: I figured it out! I searched even more and found an IE bug arcticle and you have to make sure the line-height in the parent element is set to zero. So I did that and fixed it. Thanks for taking the time to try to help me. It's appreciated.

Comment: @Amber, please create a proper Answer of **line-height in the parent element is set to zero** and accept your answer as the ***correct*** solution.